# Mejorar entreanmiento-test para prediccion en redes neuronales

Tags: python, redes-neuronales, tensorflow, keras

Estoy intentando realizar una red neuronal, estoy utilizando Keras y Google Colab. En el código les dejo el enlace a los datos para que puedan visualizarlo

```
   import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from google.colab import auth
from keras.utils import plot_model
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

auth.authenticate_user()

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

myfile = drive.CreateFile({"id": "1uJ0Y_WF1OspE46fAulNJPokdZ9gbfQYl"})
myfile.GetContentFile("EstudioCaso.csv")
frm = pd.read_csv("EstudioCaso.csv", header=None, delimiter=",,")
data = pd.read_csv("EstudioCaso.csv", delimiter=",,")

print(data) 
data.columns 
data.head() 
data.describe() 

sns.heatmap(data.isnull(), yticklabels=False, cbar=False, cmap="Blues")
columnas = data.columns
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 50))

for i in range(len(columnas)):
    plt.subplot(9, 1, i + 1)
    sns.distplot(
        data[data.columns[i]],
        kde_kws={"color": "b", "lw": 3, "label": "KDE"},
        hist_kws={"color": "y"},
    )
    plt.title(data.columns[i])

plt.tight_layout()
correlation = data.corr()
sns.heatmap(correlation, annot=True)

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
X = data.iloc[:, :-1]
y = data.iloc[:, -1]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=0)
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)


def obtener_modelo():
    modelo = Sequential([
        Dense(4, input_shape=(4, ), activation='sigmoid'),
        Dense(20, activation='relu'),
        Dropout(0.1),
        Dense(20, activation='relu'),
        Dropout(0.1),
    ])
    modelo.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="sgd", metrics="mae")
    return modelo


obtener_modelo().summary()
modelo = obtener_modelo()
es_cb = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", patience=30)

print(modelo.summary())

resultados = modelo.fit(
    X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=2000, callbacks=[es_cb]
)

plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(resultados.history["loss"])
plt.plot(resultados.history["val_loss"])
plt.title("model loss")
plt.ylabel("loss")
plt.xlabel("epoch")
plt.legend(["train", "test"], loc="upper right")


pred_sin_entrenamiento = modelo.predict(X_test)
pred_con_entrenamiento = modelo.predict(X_test)

pred_sin_entrenamiento
print(pred_sin_entrenamiento)
pred_con_entrenamiento
print(pred_con_entrenamiento)
y_test
print(y_test)


mse_con_entrenamiento = mean_squared_error(y_test, pred_con_entrenamiento)
print(mse_con_entrenamiento)

plot_model(modelo)
```

Estoy intentando mejorar el entrenamiento vs los datos del test. De forma que la predicción del modelo sea mas adecuada. Sería mejorar la calibración del modelo para que se pueda predecir una mejor eficiencia en este caso del consumo. Como mejorar esto sin forzar al modelo a tomar valores extremos que puedan dar una respuesta engañosa. Gracias de antemano.

El error que muestra es el siguiente:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_regression.py in _check_reg_targets(y_true, y_pred, multioutput, dtype)
     94     if y_true.shape[1] != y_pred.shape[1]:
     95         raise ValueError("y_true and y_pred have different number of output "
---> 96                          "({0}!={1})".format(y_true.shape[1], y_pred.shape[1]))
     97 
     98     n_outputs = y_true.shape[1]

ValueError: y_true and y_pred have different number of output (1!=20)
```

Comment: No se cómo ayudarte con la calibración, pero mis ojos lloran sangre con la estructura de ese código. Hay cosas que te pueden traicionar. Por ejemplo invocar `pred_sin_entrenamiento` tal cual quizás te muestre el valor desde el REPL pero si lo ejecutas como un script independiente es posible que no salga nada en pantalla (para esa variable por ejemplo).

Comment: LLoran sangre?? como soluciono entonces lo de pred_sin_entrenamiento :)

Comment: Simplemente usa print() cuando quieras ver el valor de una variable. Así no fallas

Comment: A vale a ver q le invento ;)

Comment: MMMMM.............sigo sin  poder calibrar ....Atasco total

Comment: Por favor, está bien que publiques todo el código, pero para que sea más facil la proxima vez, concreta la parte exacta donde te da el error y publica la traza completa de error, así nos será más fácil poder ayudarte :)

Answer (score 0):

Sigo sin saber muy bien que intentas hacer, y empiezo a sospechar que esto es un notebook de `Jupyter`. Te he saneado un poco el código, reordenado algunas lineas y anotado ciertas cosas. Creo que deberías replantearte el programa o incluso hacerlo de nuevo desde cero con otra perspectiva; o al menos reorganizar el flujo del programa o dividirlo en funciones más concisas y atómicas (que se ocupen de una única tarea). No es la respuesta que cabría esperar, pero no lo veo mucho más claro. Espero que te ayude. Un saludo

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from google.colab import auth
from keras.utils import plot_model
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

auth.authenticate_user()

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

#### Aqui creas un objeto "myfile" que no vuelves a usar nunca
myfile = drive.CreateFile({"id": "1uJ0Y_WF1OspE46fAulNJPokdZ9gbfQYl"})
myfile.GetContentFile("EstudioCaso.csv")

#### frm y data son dos dataframes iguales y "frm" no lo vuelves a usar nunca
frm = pd.read_csv("EstudioCaso.csv", header=None, delimiter=",,")
data = pd.read_csv("EstudioCaso.csv", delimiter=",,")

#### # A partir de aqui te muestras muchos datos pero no tiene sentido que lo hagas a mitad de programa
print(data) 
data.columns 
data.head() 
View = data # Creas una copia de data llamda "View" que no vuelves a usar nunca
data.describe() 

sns.heatmap(data.isnull(), yticklabels=False, cbar=False, cmap="Blues")
columnas = data.columns
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 50))

for i in range(len(columnas)):
    plt.subplot(9, 1, i + 1)
    sns.distplot(
        data[data.columns[i]],
        kde_kws={"color": "b", "lw": 3, "label": "KDE"},
        hist_kws={"color": "y"},
    )
    plt.title(data.columns[i])

plt.tight_layout()
correlation = data.corr()
sns.heatmap(correlation, annot=True)

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
X = data.iloc[:, :-1]
y = data.iloc[:, -1]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)


def obtener_modelo():
    modelo = Sequential(
        [
            Dense(4, input_shape=(4,), activation="sigmoid"),
            Dense(20, activation="relu"),
            Dropout(0.1),
            Dense(20, activation="relu"),
            Dropout(0.1),
            Dense(1),
        ]
    )
    modelo.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="sgd", metrics="mae")
    return modelo


obtener_modelo().summary() # Esto no tengo claro que vaya a funcionar
modelo = obtener_modelo() # Quizas aquí tenga sentido print(modelo.summary())

es_cb = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", patience=30)


##### Dos veces la misma operación en la variable "resultados" ?
resultados = modelo.fit(
    X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=2000, callbacks=[es_cb]
)
resultados = modelo.fit(
    X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=2000, callbacks=[es_cb]
)


plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(resultados.history["loss"])
plt.plot(resultados.history["val_loss"])
plt.title("model loss")
plt.ylabel("loss")
plt.xlabel("epoch")
plt.legend(["train", "test"], loc="upper right")

##### Dos variables distintas con la funcion repetida (contienen los mismos datos)
pred_sin_entrenamiento = modelo.predict(X_test)
pred_con_entrenamiento = modelo.predict(X_test)

pred_sin_entrenamiento # Estas tres lineas deberian llevar un print()
pred_con_entrenamiento
y_test

mse_sin_entrenamiento = mean_squared_error(y_test, pred_sin_entrenamiento)
print(mse_sin_entrenamiento)
mse_con_entrenamiento = mean_squared_error(y_test, pred_con_entrenamiento)
print(mse_con_entrenamiento)

plot_model(modelo)
```

Comment: Con lo que me has mandado (MUCHAS GRACIAS) y algunas otras correciones lo he intentado va tomando fomra pero me salta este  error: y true and y pred have different number of output (i!=20)  eso se debe al problema de calibracion creo.

Comment: Actualiza tu pregunta con la salida completa del error (las 4 o 5 últimas líneas del error)

Comment: la he acutalizado

Answer (score 0):

El error `ValueError: y_true and y_pred have different number of output (1!=20)` viene tras hacer la siguiente comprobación:`f y_true.shape[1] != y_pred.shape[1]`

Este error te quiere decir que tus valores de test `y_true` y tus valores predichos `y_pred` **son de distintas dimensiones,** y por tanto al aplicar tu métrica de regresión, para ver como de bien funciona el algoritmo, no puede funcionar porque comparas cosas distintas. En concreto `y_true` **es un array**, mientras que `y_pred` es una **matriz** (es decir tiene dos dimensiones en vez de una). Ejemplo visual:

```
#Tu y_true es:

y_true = [1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1]

#y tu y_pred es:
y_pred = [[1,0,1,0,1],
          [0,0,0,1,0],
          [1,1,1,1,1]]
```

Esto simplemente es un ejemplo inventado, pero es lo que a ti te está pasando. **Lo que tienes que hacer es que tanto "y_true" como "y_pred" tengan la misma dimensión**

### Update

¿Por que al querer comparar datos de distintas dimensiones te da un error?

Porque no es posible hayar residuos (errores) de datos distintos, al hacer una métrica de regresión, por ejemplo el MAE (Mean Absolute Error) entre conjuntos de datos, necesitas que los datos sean iguales!

Ejemplo:

Si el dato predicho por el algoritmo es 2.5 y el dato real es 4, tu MAE (error) es 1.5 (la diferencia entre lo predicho y lo real)

Si tu dato predicho es 7 y el dato real es 5, el MAE es 2

Si tu dato predicho es 9.9 y el dato real es 9.8 el MAE es 0.1

**Lo que tu estás haciendo y tu error**

Un ejemplo de lo que estas diciendo es lo siguiente:

Mi dato predicho es [5.88, 3.99, 4., 8.9] cual es la diferencia con 9.9.

El algoritmo obviamente no pude realizar el error de un vector de números, con un número, no tiene sentido, son dos estructuras distintas.

Entonces para solucionarlo tienes alguna de las dos cosas mal, o el resultado del algoritmo o los valores de **Test**. ¿Cuál de ellas es? No lo sé, eso solo puedes saberlo tú, ¿qué estás intentando predecir un dato en concreto? o un conjunto de datos? en que formato están tus datos? vectores? matrices? tensores?.

Comment: Entonces con transformar  y_pred a un array se resuelve????

Comment: Dependerá de las dimensiones que tengas. Si no has entendido la respuesta, creo que deberías tomar más cursos de formación sobre Machine learning y Deep Learning y leer más literatura al respecto. Lo que tu estás haciendo es aplicar una métrica de regresión en la que comparas el error que hay entre predecir por ejemplo 3.57 con [[2.56, 4.55], [2.44 , 7.0]]. Tu no puedes hallar los residuos de esos puesto que estás compando cosas absolutamente distintas. Como te digo lo que tienes que hacer es quue "y_true" e "y_pred" tengan la misma dimensión.

Comment: Si no eres capaz de comprender mi respuesta ni mi comentario, mi humilde recomendación y con todo el respeto es que tomes clases online/presencial o leas libros sobre Machine Learning, Deep Learning y matemáticas . Porque te faltan varios conocimientos básicos, para el problema que estás resolviendo.

Comment: Gracias por la humilde recomendacion

Comment: De nada! Si te ha molestado, lo siento no es mi intención (de hecho he votado la pregunta positivamente), mi única intención por la que estoy aquí, es para ayudar de forma desinteresada a los demás. En este caso te he dicho el problema que tienes en el código y cual es la solución a tu problema. Aun así he actualizado mi respuesta, para que la puedas entender mejor....

Comment: No me ha nolestado. Al contrario, entendi cual es la solucion al problema, claro se me hace mas complejo porque no tengo formacion en programar esto es empirico y aun me falta mucho por aprender . Estot empezando recien. Muchas gracias por la respuesta